# The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease' is not signed

Tags: linux, virtualbox, debian

I'm new to kali operating system I need to update my kali linux version to new edition. I tried to do it by "sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade" But It gave me some error like this.

Get:1 http://kali.cs.nycu.edu.tw/kali kali-rolling InRelease [41.2 kB]

Err:1 http://kali.cs.nycu.edu.tw/kali kali-rolling InRelease The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository devel@kali.org Reading package lists... Done

W: GPG error: http://kali.cs.nycu.edu.tw/kali kali-rolling InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository devel@kali.org

E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease' is not signed.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

My kali version is very old one. followed details about my version.

PRETTY_NAME="Kali GNU/Linux Rolling"
NAME="Kali GNU/Linux"
ID=kali
VERSION="2020.4"
VERSION_ID="2020.4"
VERSION_CODENAME="kali-rolling"
ID_LIKE=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="https://www.kali.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://forums.kali.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.kali.org/"
Please help me to update my version of kali linux !

Comment: It also gave me some error :   E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)

Comment: @Sonney - There is a solution to that problem [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385860/could-not-open-lock-file-var-lib-apt-lists-lock-open-13-permission-denied).  Implement the fix as outlined in the duplicate question to fix your actual problem of being unable to update your operating system. How exactly did you come to install a 3-year-old version of Kali instead of downloading the current version of it?

Comment: My answer may be flat out wrong but my own experience is that Kali will not update after some time where updates have not run .  But I deleted my flat out wrong answer

Comment: @Ramhound -  yes sir my version indicate as VERSION="2020.4"

Comment: PRETTY_NAME="Kali GNU/Linux Rolling"  
NAME="Kali GNU/Linux"  
ID=kali  
VERSION="2020.4"  
VERSION_ID="2020.4"  
VERSION_CODENAME="kali-rolling"  
ID_LIKE=debian  
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"  
HOME_URL="https://www.kali.org/"  
SUPPORT_URL="https://forums.kali.org/"  
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.kali.org/"

Comment: @Ramhound - The above quetionwhich you given as a link was same with my problem. But any solution not work for me

Comment: @Sonney - I won’t investigate anything if you’re going to include vital information as a comment. So you have resolved the permission issue, so what did the error, change to after the lock file as the correct permissions

Comment: My "flat out wrong" answer suggested reinstalling the most recent version.  Perhaps try that.

Answer (score 0):

> My kali version is very old one. followed details about my version.

Your version is very old (2020) and Kali Updater will not go back that far.  Kali Updater is a rolling updater and expects to remain up to date. I am using Kali 2023.2 here.

I am not sure the exact length of time you can go back, bu I could not upgrade a version roughly 30 months old.

So your only choice now is to back up your files and install the new version fresh.  Then recover your documents.

Comment: This answer is flat out wrong. The repository exists, it’s just the connection to the repository, isn’t secure so by default it can’t be used